# how to download video from cloudinary using nodejs?

Tags: cloudinary

I have uploaded a mp4 file using node.js on my cloudinary account. I have saved public id of video. Is there any api to download the uploaded video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `attachment` flag (`fl_attachment` in URLs) to tell the browser to download the video instead of displaying it.

For example,

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/video/upload/fl_attachment/<public_id>.mp4
```

For more information on delivery flags,
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#delivery_and_image_format_flags